# How to set the token Icon at first?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sapui5

```
var token = sap.m.Token({
    text: "i m token"
});
```

I want to use some thing like, `iconFirst: true`. I want to use the icon at first, i.e, before the text is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

As the icon of the `sap.m.Token` is not a decorative one, it does not support repositioning it.

If you want your Token to look differently, you should look into extending the Control and adding this ability in your custom implementation.

Comment: thank you so we cant reposition it...thanks for the help